# Is disinterested interchangeable with uninterested now?

Tags: word-usage

I have always thought disinterested means unbiased and uninterested means bored. However in a passage on a state wide exam the text used disinterested in place of a situation where its definition would not make sense. There was no question asking you to fix this if that is what you might be thinking. apparently some say they have become more interchangeable.

Comment: Have you looked them up in a dictionary?  If not, please do so, and then share your findings here and rephrase your question accordingly?

Comment: See [usage note](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disinterested) on *disinterested* in *American Heritage Dictionary.*

Answer (score 1):

*to be interested in* really means a few things. It can mean *to have your attention held by* something, or it can mean *to have a desire in the outcome of*. Both come from the Latin *[interesse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intersum#Latin)*, which literally means *to exist between*, but also has the meanings *to attend to* (as in to have your attention), and *to concern*, so the roots go way back.

Back to colloquial English: *disinterested* can be used anywhere *uninterested* can be used. They both mean *paying no attention to* but the *dis-* sense includes *having no concern about*.

On the other hand, the same is not true of *disinteresting* and *uninteresting*. you say *that's interesting* or *that's uninteresting* but never *that's disinteresting*. Why that is may be lost in the mists of time.

Answer (score -1):

"Disinterested" is used to mean "uninterested" by the uneducated. Educated native English speakers who value the distinction between words would not dream of using it in this way. The answer to your question depends on what you read and who you talk to. If you read what I write, no!